# Render asynchronously fetched data

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I'm new to react and naïvely want to do the following, attempting to render some images from Cloudinary.

(N.B.: I can log the images, I just get the error attempting to render them).

This is an overly simplified version, but I reckon you will spot where I'm going wrong:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const Album = () => {
  const getPhotos = async () => {
    const allPhotosWithTag = await axios.get(
      process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_TAG
    );

    const photoArray = allPhotosWithTag.data.resources;
    photoArray.map((photo) => <img href={`${process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD}/${photo.public_id}.${photo.format}`} />);
  };

  return <div>{getPhotos()}</div>;
};

export default Album;
```

I get

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object
> Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
> array instead.

I'd appreciate someone guiding me through this and letting me know where I'm failing!

Comment: use effects https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: `getPhotos` returns a promise, which is an Object. And the error says

> Objects are not valid as a React child

A solution for your problem is to make the async action just to fetch the image sources. Then, you render the `img`s tags with those sources.

```js
const Album = () => {
  const [photosSources, setPhotosSources] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const allPhotosWithTag = await axios.get(
        process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_TAG
      );
      const photoArray = allPhotosWithTag.data.resources;
      setPhotosSources(
        photoArray.map(
          photo =>
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD}/${photo.public_id}.${photo.format}`
        )
      );
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {photosSources.map(photoSource => (
        <img href={photoSource} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is working great, thank you so much! I'll need to refine it I guess, or see if Cloudinary is responsive enough, as the gallery looks a bit clumsy to load. Thank you!

Comment: (I just added an empty array before the end of the useEffect hook, or it fell into an infinite loop).

Comment: Sure! Without it, the `useEffect` will run on each render. I updated the answer with that. 